# Oracle Permission USER and VPD

Tags: oracle11g

What permissions need user to avoid VPD? I want create user A to VPD policy and user B without VPD policy in this same schema. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant user B the EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY privilege as documented in [Oracle Virtual Private Database and Oracle Label Security Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm#DBSEG905).